# Creating complex layouts in Swift/Cocoa for MAC OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am currently working on a Swift/Cocoa application for MAC OS, and I am new to this stack of technologies. I am faced with the need to find the right controls to create the following window:

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx34E9rSMtcNenhXYnBrTlJNTVE/view]

I am using xCode (the latest version that is not beta). I'd like to ask your advice on:

1. What control (s) should be preferred for the left-hand side area (NSTableView? - but how can I bind separate lines to some actions in this case? e.g. transitions between storyboard views) and the right-hand side one? Also, I am not sure how this selection in the left-hand side area could be implemented if I don't use a table.
2. This application assumes all windows of the fixed size with some navigation between them. Could I use a storyboard for that purpose?
3. How can I draw this arrow pointing to the bottom from the topmost gray area?
4. Since all the windows share the left-hand side area, can I create a sort of user control (like in ASP.NET WebForms) that could be reused across the app?

Also, I'd appreciate any examples that you could suggest. The only ones that I have found so far are in Objective-C (while I have to use Swift) and a bit outdated. No similar layout has been found (I have been looking into the Apple Development website).

Please don't hesitate to ask any questions.

Comment: Could someone please at least refer me to some samples illustrating the applications like above (I would even be fine with paid ones)? The documentation of the latests Swift/Cocoa is poor, and no examples are accessible for free that are worthwhile. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have converted your layout to use the formatting features used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), including using the built-in image upload. You should also note that the Q&A format does not use the greetings used in chat formats, so I have elided those for you. In this way you may get an answer more quickly. Note that asking for links to internet examples or tutorials is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices! I will follow the best practices from now on.. Hope to get some reply soon from somebody.. The technology is tricky, and there are too few resources/examples that would illustrate my case. The layout is a bit more complex than the examples and articles that I have found so far.

Comment: If you want to follow best-practice then you need to add some attempts at coding to your question. Add some non-functioning swift example and ask what can be done to achieve your desired goals. This will be more effective than a *list of demand*, which is basically what you have at the moment. Your question implies SO is a "code for hire" service which it is not. So - give some code to get some code ....

Comment: Okay, once I have more of this code, I will add it to this post/create a new one. Thanks.

Comment: Good plan. Yes, add it to the post using [edit]. Don't make a new question as these would be flagged as duplicates by the (human) editors....